# Jquery mobile listview with filter shows wrong results

Tags: android, iphone, jquery-mobile

I am working on jquery mobile to build some apps which requires listview with filter option , my database has more than 300 records to show in the listview , if i type any values in the search text box it shows repeated records in the listview even though i dont have any duplicate items in the database.

So i checked with jquery mobile wiki site example using given below link there also same thing is happening please some help me

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-performance.html

go to that link type "bm" in the search box -> it shows all the list view rows as BMW ???

Highly appreciated your time and effort to help me on this.

Comment: I believe they added duplicate records just to show the performance,
as the title says "list-performance-test"
i also think it has something to do with the for loop you use to output the records.

Comment: I am pretty sure that they dont have duplicates either.I have checked my records count, there was no duplicate as well in the sqlite db table i am clueless where to look for ?

Comment: In your listview the records you append are more than 300?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its my mistake that without clearing the db entries I adding records on and on thats the issue caused these duplicates sorry